# Как добавить значения нескольких массивов php в mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо вводить данные целыми массивами и сохранять их в базе mysql.

input.php

```
<form action="addvmstodb.php" method="post">
  List of VM names: <textarea name="VMNAMES" cols="25" rows="5"></textarea>
  List of VM IP's: <textarea name="VMIPS" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
  List of VM PWD's: <textarea name="VMPWDS" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
  VMs Group name: <textarea name="GROUPNAME" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

addvmstodb.php

```php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pwd","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$input_VMNAMES = isset($_POST['VMNAMES'])?$_POST['VMNAMES']:"";
$VMNAMES_array = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $input_VMNAMES));

$input_VMIPS = isset($_POST['VMIPS'])?$_POST['VMIPS']:"";
$VMIPS_array = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $input_VMIPS));

$input_VMPWDS = isset($_POST['VMPWDS'])?$_POST['VMPWDS']:"";
$VMPWDS_array = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $input_VMPWDS));

$VMGROUPNAME=$_POST['GROUPNAME'];

for( $i = 0 ; $i < count( $VMNAMES_array ) ; $i++ ) {
  $INSERTQUERY="insert into vmlist (vm_name,vm_ip,vm_pwd,groupname) values ('".$VMNAMES_array[$i]."', '".$VMIPS_array[$i]."', '".$VMPWDS_array[$i]."', '$VMGROUPNAME')";
  $result=mysqli_query($con,$INSERTQUERY);
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Массивы получаю нормально. Например, `echo $VMNAMES_array[1];` возвращает верное значение. Но данные в базу не добавляются и в логах висят ошибки вида

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /path/to/folder/addvmstodb.php on line 81

Куда копать и как починить?

p.s. В php я полный новичок.

UPD
var_dump($INSERTQUERY);

```
string(99) "insert into vmlist (vm_name,vm_ip,vm_pwd) values ('host1', '111.111.111.1', 'pwd1')"
string(99) "insert into vmlist (vm_name,vm_ip,vm_pwd) values ('host2', '111.111.111.2', 'pwd2)"
string(99) "insert into vmlist (vm_name,vm_ip,vm_pwd) values ('host3', '111.111.111.3', 'pwd3')"
```

var_dump ($result);

```
NULL NULL NULL
```

var_dump ($con);

```
(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(7) ["client_info"]=> string(14) "5.5.47-MariaDB" ["client_version"]=> int(50547) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(5) ["host_info"]=> string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(14) "5.5.47-MariaDB" ["server_version"]=> int(50547) ["stat"]=> string(133) "Uptime: 12357 Threads: 1 Questions: 173 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 3 Flush tables: 2 Open tables: 27 Queries per second avg: 0.014" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(69) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php  - посмотрите на порядок параметров

Comment: Посмотрел. Пока что не проникся.

Comment: а если посмотреть в секцию **Список параметров** http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php#refsect1-function.mysql-query-parameters  ?

Comment: И всё равно непонятна суть проблемы. Не могли бы вы объяснить что именно не так в вышеприведённом коде?

Comment: Вы забыли указать, где именно вы вызываете `var_dump`. Лучше исправьте код так, чтобы в основном блоке было видно эти вызовы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создаете коннект при помощи расширения `mysqli`, а для выполнения запроса вызываете функцию `mysql_query` из расширения `mysql`.

Замените ее на функцию `mysqli_query` и все должно заработать

А если добавите использование prepared statement и обработку ошибок, то вообще будет конфетка

```
$INSERTQUERY = "insert into vmlist (vm_name, vm_ip, vm_pwd, groupname) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $INSERTQUERY);
if (!$stmt)
  die(mysqli_error($con));
$name = null;
$ip = null;
$pwd = null;
if (!mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $name, $ip, $pwd, $VMGROUPNAME))
  die(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
for ($i = 0; $i < count($VMNAMES_array); $i++ ) {
  $name = $VMNAMES_array[$i];
  $ip = $VMIPS_array[$i];
  $pwd = $VMPWDS_array[$i];
  $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  if (!$result)
    die(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
}
$stmt = null;
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Однако, не починилось... mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in addvmstodb.php on line 81

Comment: @AlexandrBlinov используйте var_dump и посмотрите, что у вас за первый аргумент.

Comment: Для result - первый аргумент это $con, в нём ожидаемо находится инфо о соединении. Остальные добавил.

Comment: @AlexandrBlinov Ничего не ожидаемо. Сделайте `var_dump($con)`

Comment: Спасибо, эта версия работает. Но всё ж хочу понять почему не работает изначальная. Добавил дамп $con в вопрос

Comment: @AlexandrBlinov А теперь добавьте весь код с дампами. А то у Вас в коде формируется один запрос, а выводится совершенно другой

Answer (score 1):

У вас опечатка в строке

```
$result=mysql_query($con,$INSERTQUERY);
```

Забыли i, должно быть

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,$INSERTQUERY);
```

Comment: Я вижу две одинаковые строки.

Comment: И правда, у меня та же самая опечатка. Исправил.

Comment: Действительно опечатка. Изменил на mysqli, но всё равно код нежизнеспособен =(